# When I start playing games my second monitor occasionaly disconnects

Tags: multiple-monitors

I got this second VGA monitor plugged with HDMI to VGA adapter the resolution is less than 1080p...
I usually got yourube on that monitor and both monitors are plugged on same GPU.

So when I start playing any games everything is fine but after few minutes second monitor goes blackscreen for few seconds and windows does the unplug plug sound.
I'm not moving with the cables or pc or banging desk nothing it literally does only when playing games or maybe on desktop too but on desktop it's not so often to bother.

Does it have to do with GPU rendering 3D in fullscreen while also rendering desktop video or could it be something else like a cable?

Just played 2 games together lasting almost an hour with borderless instead of fullscreen and no blackscreens occured...
I'm not sure if it's just a coincidence or borderless fixes the issue I will sure comment if I get blackscreens on borderless.

So why does the monitor sometimes blackscreen when playing game in fullscreen?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for the GPU to crash at times.

Try following:

- Check that the GPU fan is working properly and no dust accumulated (otherwise overheat can trigger it)
- Install latest drivers (OS and driver version can be an issue sometimes).
- Bent pins in VGA cable can cause errors in transmission.
- See that the power supplied to the monitor is rated as indicated on the monitor.

Also test to see if same occurs with only the monitor with VGA attached.